# Check if time elapsed since date is more than X days

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I need to create a PHP script that pulls the timestamps of various stuff from a database (logs, messages, logins, etc) and removes them if they are older than X amount of days. I am poor at doing work with time and am a bit stumped on the best way to do this.

I realize I could separate the day/month/year in the string using explode() and compare these with a bunch of If statements, but would like to use a more efficient method. Something like the following would be the correct way to do this correct?

```
$dt = "2011-03-19 10:05:44";

//if $dt is older than 90 days
if((time()-(60*24*90)) > strtotime($dt))
{

}
```

Subtract (minutes*hours*days) from time() or are the numbers wrong?

Comment: you could just run a `delete from foo where your_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL X DAYS)`

Comment: That is a good option although its a little more in depth than my example so using DT in PHP is probably better suited in this case.

Comment: well i can answer what you post, not guess at what you left out

Comment: You sure NOW() - DAYS works? I just tried SELECT * FROM `tbladminlog` WHERE logintime > (NOW() - 5) to pull the records from last 5 days and it returned only those from today.

Comment: Ah it was "DAY" not "DAYS". Thanks, I think I will use this too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` class for this. Example:

```
$dt = "2011-03-19 10:05:44";
$date = new DateTime($dt);
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now->diff($date);
if($diff->days > 90) {
    echo 'its greater than 90 days';
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I wasn't aware of the DateTime class.

Comment: since he's removing from db, there's no need to extract them just to do the date functions

Comment: @Dagon actually yes could also use intervals on queries

Comment: Dagon: You are right but in this case I have associated tables, such as "message" and "message_replies". I need to find older messages and then remove each reply based on that message's ID, why I have to go this route.

Comment: I am simple minded so I will just go with what I know rather than complicate it and blow something up. Thank you though :)

Comment: I am just not overly familiar with doing any "complex" operations in SQL syntax only. If you would like to provide an example that addresses that situation I would love to check it out and try it.